# Please explain the nested switch-case statements in the following C program and the corresponding output

Tags: c

On compiling and running the code below, we get the output as stated. Please explain the output. `case 2` is nested in `case 0` so the program shouldn't print anything at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=5;
    switch ( 2 ) {
        case 0:
            for (  i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
        case 1:
            printf("A i=%d\n",i);
        case 2:
            printf("B i*i=%d\n",i*i);
            };
        case 3:
            printf("done");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* OUTPUT
B i*i=25
A i=6
B i*i=36
A i=7
B i*i=49
A i=8
B i*i=64
A i=9
B i*i=81
done
*/
```

Comment: Who designs abominations like this?

Comment: Duff.....See Duff's Device....

Comment: abominations it does, but i still don't know why the initializing statement of for loop is not running? i.e. why `i` is start from 5 not 0 ?

Comment: @billhoo: the `for` loop initialization isn't run because the `for` loop isn't entered normally - it's jumped into.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I can't edit your comment, but I missed getting a link: [Duff's device on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: @MichaelBurr got it, and `Duff's Device` explain it well.

Comment: Mr. Duff has a lot to answer for, considering the amount of wasted time he cost. @BillHoo: Really, you don't even want to know how this works. If you ever encounter code like this in real life, wipe it out, erase it, and shoot whoever wrote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `switch` statement is just a jump into the middle of a `for` loop (at `case` label 2).  Then the code executes the `for` loop.  Pretty much equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=5;

    goto label_2;

    for (  i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
        printf("A i=%d\n",i);
      label_2:
        printf("B i*i=%d\n",i*i);
    };

  label_3:
    printf("done");

    return 0;
}
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: When does the switch statement behave like this? Is it when we have  switch(const_expr)?

Comment: @ajay: the controlling expression of the switch statement doesn't have to be a constant expression for this behavior.  The switch statement just jumps to the matching case (or default label or past the switch body depending on whether the controlling expression matches a case).  Once the jump occurs, execution proceeds as normal (with `break` statements being valid inside the switch body).

Comment: so switch is just like a goto statement where instead of labeling statement/block-of-statements with identifiers, we label them with integers?

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (  i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    case 1:
        printf("A i=%d\n",i);
    case 2:
        printf("B i*i=%d\n",i*i);
        };
```

So case 2 is inside the for loop, hence the repetition in the outputs. With a case you need to put in a break or it executes every case after the one it switches to.

```
switch(2)
case 1: //blah
case 2: //blah
case 3: //blah
```

For this example above the code in cases 2 and 3 are ran whereas normally you write:

```
switch(2)
case 1: //blah
    break;
case 2: //blah
    break;
case 3: //blah
    break;
```

In which case only case 2 is ran

Comment: abominations it does, but i still don't know why the initializing statement of for loop is not running? i.e. why i is start from 5 not 0 ? thx

Comment: because it leaps into the for loop part of the way though so the initialising statement i=0; doesn't get ran. Instead initial value of i=5 is used